Should a semicolon be used to attach an adverb like "always" to another sentence fragment?
I'll keep it quick and to the point.
I'm aware semi-colons are used to join two related independent clauses but would it apply in this instance?

"After all this time; always."

For context, this is taken from a quote from Harry Potter where one character is questioning another's continued love for someone long after their passing so they ask, "After all this time?" and he replied "Always." I'm trying to rephrase it as a statement rather than a question and answer to title a photo album to my partner for our anniversary.

I feel the most impact those lines would bring, pertaining to your situation and context would be in this fashion:

After all this time-
always.

Why the change in line and the dash?
The change in line is for the abrupt impact of the word "always" which seems to fit to the context.
The use of dash is to enamel the use of "always" and act as a support to the reader's mind, enabling them to really feel the significance "always" brings to the table.

Since your context is poetic, you can do whatever you want with the punctuation. The semi colon is fine there. So would be a period:

After all this time. Always.

In fact, I think that puts a little more emphasis on Always. Compare a comma:

After all this time, always.

Which I think is a little less strong.
You could also try a line break:

After all this time
Always

If you're in a position to be able to centre the text, even better.
All of these are correct grammatically (my fave test for semi colons is to split into two sentences and see if it's ok: these are sentences even though they are technically fragments) but you don't have to be ok grammatically when you're writing poems, titles, or dialog - this is dialog because it's a message from you to the album recipient. I mean "My Best Beaches" isn't a sentence, technically, but it's a fine album title, right?
It's not my album, but if it was I would go with the period both because it sounds stronger and because it eliminates any "hey a semi colon what's up with that is it ok to use one there" factor.

Think of it this way:
From a space to a comma to a semicolon to a full stop:

the pause gets longer and
the break is more abrupt.

You may use all of these punctuation marks interchangeably in all places, but the rhythm of your writing will change.

I. Will. Not. Come.

sounds chopped and has a strong emphasis on every single word of that "sentence", for example, while the following soundss breathless and driven:

I will not come no matter what you say and I won't discuss this no shut up I'm not listening go away.

The "rules" of style guides are only conventions that you can follow or not. You employ punctuation to whichever effect you want to achieve.

Please be aware that you are asking here about punctuation in the context of creative writing. If you are interested in English grammar, please ask your question on english.stackexchange.com.
